# Get item weight from WooCommerce order

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the quantity, total and weight for each item in an order.

**Quantity and total work perfectly**, but when I add `$item->get_weight(),` it breaks my plugin.

Here is my code; can anyone explain what's up with `get_weight()`?

```
foreach ($order->items as $item) {
  fputs($file, implode("|", array(
    $item->get_quantity(),
    $item->get_total(),      
    $item->get_weight(),
  )));
}
```

Comment: First use `$product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object` and then `$product_weight = $product->get_weight(); // Get the product weight`

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
foreach ($order->items as $item) {
  fputs($file, implode("|", array(
    $item->get_quantity(),
    $item->get_total(),      
    $item->get_product()->get_weight(),
  )));
}
```